# Insert new values in single column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, database, linq

I need to insert values into the database. In my case while user enter any message click update button that message need to update on `Chats` column in `comma`(,) separated values.

I tried in this method:

[image: This is demo of my Database Looks like]

I need output like this:

[image: This want output look like this.]

How to write SQL query for this method?

Comment: Hi. Please if you use image, embed them in tue question and not just link the source image.

Comment: Looks like something you should not do at all. Why would you denormalize data?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
  DECLARE @ID INT;
  UPDATE [User] SET Chats=(STUFF( (SELECT ','+us.Chats  FROM  [User] us WHERE us.id=@ID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')) +','+N'NEW CHATS'
  WHERE id=@ID
```

Comment: Thank you @GertArnold,i modified it

Comment: Replace new query @yuvaraj anbazhagan